# Returning latest record for each column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample Table

```
+--------+------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+
| FileID |    Date    |     Activity     | Assigned_By | Responsible |
+--------+------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+
|    123 | 2016/01/01 | Work in progress | Foo1        | Bob         | 
|    234 | 2016/01/01 | Work in progress | Foo2        | Smith       | 
|    123 | 2016/01/02 | Escalated        | NULL        | NULL        | 
|    123 | 2016/01/03 | Need reassign    | NULL        | NULL        | 
|    123 | 2016/01/03 | Reassigned       | Foo2        | John        | 
|    234 | 2016/01/03 | Completed        | NULL        | NULL        |
|    123 | 2016/01/04 | Completed        | NULL        | NULL        |
+--------+------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

My query:

```
SELECT FileID,
       Date,
       Activity,
       Assigned_By,
       Responsible
FROM (
      SELECT fooTable.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Separator
     ) fooTable
INNER JOIN randomTable ON fooTable.FileID = randomTable.ID
WHERE fooTable.Separator = 1;
```

Returns:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| FileID |    Date    | Activity  | Assigned By | Responsible |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|    234 | 2016/01/03 | Completed | NULL        | NULL        |
|    123 | 2016/01/04 | Completed | NULL        | NULL        |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Desired results - Returning each row with the LATEST column record of each unique FileID with the latest DATE:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| FileID |    Date    | Activity  | Assigned By | Responsible |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|    234 | 2016/01/03 | Completed | Foo2        | John        |
|    123 | 2016/01/04 | Completed | Foo1        | Bob         |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

I kind of understand why the query isn't working, because it is only returning the latest row (assigned 1 by row_number), so therefore I will receive the first ROW record for that unique FileID based on the descending date. But I don't know how to fix it.

EDIT: Something else I realized is that MAX() will not work for Assigned_By and Responsible (I think) since it will return the greater alphabetical name...

Comment: You would need to query this table an additional time for each nullable column. You would do your current query for FileID, Date, Activity (assuming Activity is not nullable) then left join another query for Assigned By and another for Responsible. The additional queries would have the added where clause of "WHERE {column} IS NOT NULL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want using conditional aggregation:

```
WITH t AS (
      SELECT FileID, Date, Activity, Assigned_By, Responsible
      FROM fooTable INNER JOIN 
           randomTable
           ON fooTable.FileID = randomTable.ID
     )
SELECT FileID, MAX(Date) as date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN Activity END) as Activity,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_nonnull = 1 THEN Assigned_By END) as Assigned_By,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_nonnull = 1 THEN Responsible END) as Responsible
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS seqnum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FileID
                                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN AssignedBy IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), Date DESC
                               ) AS seqnum_notnull
      FROM t
     ) t
GROUP BY FileID;
```

Comment: Mr. Linoff, if manipulating data was world hunger, you would solve it. This works brilliantly, a big thank you to you.

Answer (score 2):

You use joins or you can use FIRST_VALUE, like this:

```
SELECT 
  FileID,
  FIRST_VALUE(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY Date DESC ROWS  BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Date,
  FIRST_VALUE(Activity) OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY CASE WHEN Activity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, Date DESC ROWS  BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Activity,
  FIRST_VALUE(Assigned_By) OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY CASE WHEN Assigned_By IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, Date DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Assigned_By,
  FIRST_VALUE(Responsible) OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY CASE WHEN Responsible IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, Date DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Responsible
FROM fooTable
INNER JOIN randomTable ON fooTable.FileID = randomTable.ID
WHERE fooTable.Separator = 1;
```

Comment: How does this prevent the `NULL` values?  It seems equivalent to the OP's code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- in db2 the default is to not include null values for first_value -- I have not tested this in sql server but I was making that assumption.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- yeah sql server does not allow you to ignore nulls like db2 and oracle -- have to add in another order by clause to make it work as my edit -- thanks for finding the problem.

Comment: @Hogan This is a great answer after the update, the only issue is with additional columns is the query gets a bit messy, so the usage of Gordon's conditional aggregation is cleaner. Still, a big thank you.

Comment: @Simon -- you're welcome.  This is a useful answer to know if you ever need some columns first based on date and other columns first based on a different ordering.  Depending on a number of other factors it may be faster than other solutions.